# Determine the objectClass of a given id from LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

What is the best way to get the objectClass name of a give id.

My input should be something like "IDNSKF" 
My output should be Group or Person or Computer..

I use the following code but however some times in the `distinguishedName` i don't find `OU=Groups` although the object is group

Code:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://local.be");
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        searcher.Filter = "(&(cn=variable))";
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
        string s = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
        if (s.IndexOf("OU=Groups") > -1)
            return Groups;
        if (s.IndexOf("OU=Users") > -1)
            return Users;
        if (s.IndexOf("OU=Computers") > -1)
            return Computer;
```

Thanks

Comment: It's just an attribute of the entry. What have you tried?

Comment: Hello EJP thanks for your reply, I updated my post. it works but i would like to have the best way to perform this according to Performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share with you the solution i found:

```
SearchResult result = directorySearcher.FindOne();
        if (result == null)
            return new LocalPermissionEntry(accessRule);

        ResultPropertyValueCollection userValueCollection = result.Properties["objectClass"];

        // check if the entry is a group or a user.
        if (userValueCollection.Contains("group"))
            return new GroupPermissionEntry(accessRule);
        if (userValueCollection.Contains("person") || userValueCollection.Contains("user"))
            return new UserPermissionEntry(accessRule);

        return new LocalPermissionEntry(accessRule);
```